# Prove/Disprove asymptotics claims

Tags: asymptotics, computational-complexity

> **Prove/Disprove:**
>
> $(1) \log((\sum _{k=1}^n(k^2))^3)= \mathcal{O}(n^2)$
>
> $(2) \ 2^{n^3}=\mathcal{O}(3^{n^2})$
>
> $(3) \ \forall f(n):f(n)=\mathcal{O}(\log n) \Rightarrow 2^{f(n)}=\mathcal{O}(n)$
>
> $(4)  \ \forall f(n):2^{f(n)}=\mathcal{O}(n) \Rightarrow f(n)=\mathcal{O}(\log n)$

**My try:**

$(1)$ is true.

$(2)$ is not true, but not sure how to prove it.

$(3)$ is not true.

$(4)$ is true.

Any help with $(2)$ appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that 
$$2^{n^3}=2^{n^2\cdot n}=2^{2n^2}\cdot2^{n^2(n-2)}=4^{n^2}\cdot2^{n^2(n-2)}.$$
Can you finish?

Comment: $4^{n^2} \geq 3^{n^2}$ and we're done?

Comment: I think it would be more clear saying $(\frac 43)^{n^2}\cdot2^{n^2(n-2)}\rightarrow \infty$, because both factors approach $\infty$ and thus $2^{n^3}\ne\mathcal O(3^{n^2})$.